# Objective C - Fetch Results Controller fetching less objects after insert

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller, reloaddata

I have a chat panel in an iOS application using NSFetchResultController. Fetching occurs as:

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }

    DataSource *dataSource = [DataSource getInstance];
    [NSFetchedResultsController deleteCacheWithName:@"MessageList"];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:_CHAT_MESSAGE_ENTITY_ inManagedObjectContext:dataSource.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

    //Predicate
    DataClass *dataClass = [DataClass getInstance];
    NSPredicate *predicate;
    if ([self.chatType intValue] == SINGULAR_CHAT_TYPE) {

        Contact *receiver = [self.members objectAtIndex:0];

        predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(senderUid LIKE %@ AND receiverUid LIKE %@) OR (senderUid LIKE %@ AND receiverUid LIKE %@)", [dataClass getKeychainValueWithKey:_USER_ID_IDENTIFIER_], receiver.contactUid, receiver.contactUid, [dataClass getKeychainValueWithKey:_USER_ID_IDENTIFIER_]];
    }
    else { // group chat

    }

    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"messageDate" ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = @[sortDescriptor];

    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:dataSource.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"messageId" cacheName:@"MessageList"];
    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
        // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
        // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
        NSLog(@"%@:Unresolved error in fetchedResultsController performFetch %@List, %@", _CHAT_MESSAGE_ENTITY_,error, [error userInfo]);
        //abort();
    }

    return _fetchedResultsController;
}

- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    [self.chatTableView beginUpdates];
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo
           atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
{
    switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [self.chatTableView  insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [self.chatTableView  deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        default:
            return;
    }
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject
       atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
      newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
{
    UITableView *tableView = self.chatTableView;

    switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

//        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
//            [self configureCell:[chatTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] atIndexPath:indexPath];
//            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}

- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    [self.chatTableView reloadData];
    [self.chatTableView  endUpdates];
}
```

This fetching works normal, when I open the view controller all previous messages are seen on the table as they should be. However, when I type a new message and press "send" button, not only the new message but also last message before it is not getting fetched. 
I get the number of rows, see there are 2 missing objects. 
Still, if I stop app and run again, these last 2 messages are getting fetched and shown.

The same problem is occuring conversations panel. In other words, after sending message my conversation view controller needs to be updated. However, its last conversations (chosen one) is getting lost.

I'm saving the message and conversations as:

```
    DataSource *ds = [DataSource getInstance];
    ChatMessage *newMsg = (ChatMessage*)[ds createInsertObject:_CHAT_MESSAGE_ENTITY_];
    [newMsg loadFromDictionary:tmpDict];


    Chat *chat = (Chat*)[ds findOrCreateWithIdentifier:[[headers objectForKey:CHAT_TYPE] stringValue]:[headers objectForKey:@"receiverUid"] :_CHAT_ENTITY_];
    [chat loadHeaders:headers andMessage:newMsg];
    newMsg.chat = chat;

    [ds coreDataSaveContext];
```

And after this saving, I'm telling to my chat view controller:

```
- (void)refreshPage {

    [self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:nil];
    [self.chatTableView reloadData];
    [self takeTableContentsUp];
}
```

Am I missing something about fetch result controller? Why is this problem happening and how can I fix it?

Thank you!

**EDIT:** If I remove "Chat" entity in saving message, just save the message everyting is ok for chat panel. Thus the problem is multiple entities interacted with each other. 
How should i edit and save 2 entities to core data, and fetch without problem?

Comment: Maybe unrelated, but don't reloadData within a beginUpdates/endUpdates block - it is unnecessary because the relevant updates should be happening courtesy of the insertRowsAtIndexPaths,deleteRowsAtIndexPaths, etc, within didChangeObject.

Comment: You mean, i should delete "end updates" shouldn't i? I thought this, but not sure. Thank you :) @pbasdf

Comment: No, remove the `reloadData` from `controllerDidChangeContent`.

Comment: ... but keep `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates`.

Comment: Intersting. I saw a lot of people using this. Ok, i removed it. Thank you. @pbasdf